# Segfault when inserting with iterator

Tags: c++, string, iterator, segmentation-fault

The following code segfaults after the loop repeats 16 times. When debugging with gdb, `*col` is equal to 'a' except on the iteration when it segfaults, in which it suddenly becomes '\036'. This was tested on both gcc 6.30 and clang 3.8.1 on WSL Debian.

What could be the cause of this error?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(void) {
    std::string line = "";
    std::string::iterator col = line.begin();
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        line.insert(col, 'a');
    }
}
```

Edit: Yes, there is an infinite loop and I am aware of that. This is just for the MCVE.

Comment: After you fix this iterator issue, you'll see that this is also an infinite loop that fills up the `string` until the program crashes. You may have already known that though.

Comment: Yeah, the infinite loop was just for the example for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inserting elements into your string, the string may reallocating itself and then your iterator won't be point to the begin of your string and it won't be valid.

So do this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string line = "";
    std::string::iterator col = line.begin();
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        line.insert(col, 'a');
        col = line.begin();
    }
}
```

Note that this fixes the iterator issue only, but your infinite loop will extend your string infinitely until your program crashes.

Comment: What should I do instead? Store an index instead of the iterator?

Comment: Yeah look at the [function overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) for `insert`. You can avoid using the `begin()` iterator at all and just use the `basic_string& insert( size_type index, size_type count, CharT ch );` version of the function. Like `line.insert(0, 1, 'a');`

Comment: Would this also apply to iterators of other containers like vectors?

Comment: @SuperStormer yes